# uibutton image not shown in simulator

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, uiimage, uilabel

I a trying to do an uibutton with image and text, in xib it looks fine but in the simulator the image is missing, and I don't know why.

xib:

[image]

the uibutton settings:

[image]

[image]

the look in simulator:

[image]

Comment: Try making it a little bit bigger. Make the hight e.g. 30 and see what happens.

Comment: nothing changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple way is to take UIView and add UIImageView,UILabel as SubView using interface builder. Then add a transparent button all over the UIView. I hope your problem will be solved.